# Getting nulls at output with System.out.printf

Tags: java, null

I have method, which does the following:

- counts the number of lowercase vowels
- adds a star to a string array for each vowel
- prints the number of vowels and the stars

The output looks like this:

```
Sentence: There is a wolf in the woods
There were: 
1 A's null* 
3 E's null*** 
2 I's null** 
3 O's null*** 
0 U's null
```

The problem is that I don't know why those null keywords appear there.

Could you please explain how they got there and how to get rid of them?

```
    public void printStars (String inputString) {
    int[] vowelCounter = new int[5];
    String[] starCounter = new String[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++) {
        if (inputString.charAt(i) == 'a') {
            vowelCounter[0]++;
            starCounter[0] += "*";
        }
        else if (inputString.charAt(i) == 'e') {
            vowelCounter[1]++;
            starCounter[1] += "*";
        }
        else if (inputString.charAt(i) == 'i') {
            vowelCounter[2]++;
            starCounter[2] += "*";
        }
        else if (inputString.charAt(i) == 'o') {
            vowelCounter[3]++;
            starCounter[3] += "*";
        }
        else if (inputString.charAt(i) == 'u') {
            vowelCounter[4]++;
            starCounter[4] += "*";
        }
    }
    System.out.println(inputString);
    System.out.println("There were: ");
    System.out.printf("%d A's %s %n", vowelCounter[0], starCounter[0]);
    System.out.printf("%d E's %s %n", vowelCounter[1], starCounter[1]);
    System.out.printf("%d I's %s %n", vowelCounter[2], starCounter[2]);
    System.out.printf("%d O's %s %n", vowelCounter[3], starCounter[3]);
    System.out.printf("%d U's %s %n", vowelCounter[4], starCounter[4]);
}
```

Comment: Don't you want to count uppercase letters too, as in "Is it working?" and "How would I know?"

Comment: @Andreas I also noticed that uppercase characters do not get counted. My understanding is that by calling the toLowerCase() method on the string prior to processing it, the uppercase characters will also get included in the count. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not initialize values of `starCounter`, so by default all the values are null.

Add this at the beginning :

```
for (int i = 0; i < starCounter.length(); i++) {
   starCounter[i] = "";
}
```

Comment: Or call [`Arrays.fill(starCounter, "")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object-)

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] starCounter = new String[5];
```

When created, all elemets are null.

As a consequence, `starCounter[1] += "*"` -> "null*"

You can do, for example, an update method:

```
public static void updateStartCounter(String[] starCounter, int index, String addedValue){
    if (starCounter[index] == null){
        starCounter[index] = addedValue;
    } else {
        starCounter[index] += addedValue;
    }
}
```

And instead of doing: `starCounter[0] += "*";`, You can do: `updateStartCounter(starCounter, 0, "*");`.

My method will be useless for non-vowels.

You can create `List<String> starCounter = new ArrayList<>(5);` and do the same tricks there. Before the printing area, just check if the size of `starCounter` is greater than 0 and then do your printing.

Comment: That will then print `null` for vowels that are not present.

Answer (score 0):

As stated on the other answers when created `starCounter` has all its elements set to `null` therefore every time you append a `*` is going to have a leading `null`. Another solution you can use is to create and initialize your variable on the same line so instead of
`String[] starCounter = new String[5];`
use:
`String[] starCounter = {"","","","",""};`